# C - print star pattern in different arrangement

Tags: c

My homework needs to print out the star pattern by using for loop as below:

```
!!!!!
!!!!
!!!
!!
!
```

Here is my loop:

```
    int i, j;
    for(i=5;i<=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf("!");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Actually I have succeeded to print out the pattern as below already:

```
! 
!! 
!!! 
!!!! 
!!!!!
```

By the following loop:

```
    int i, j;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf("!");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Now I am confused why pattern 1 can't be printed, as there are no errors found.
Also the output window will get down when I go ahead to run the program.

My Xcode is Ver 4.4.1

Comment: This is plain C, by the way. Not Objective-C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This loop cannot execute anything :

```
for(i=5;i<=1;i--)
```

It says "start with `i = 5`, and while `i <= 1`; do `i--`".

At the first iteration, i is already > 1, so your loop doesn't even enter.

What you should do is reverse the condition:

```
for (i = 5; i>= 1; i--)
```

This way, you'll loop by starting with `i = 5`, and perform `i--` while `i >= 1`.

General rule of thinking for a `for` loop :

```
for (A; B; C)
{
    D;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
A;
while (B)
{
    C;
    D;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I understand that the problem is on my logic! your explanation is very great for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your first code sample you write the following:

```
for(i=5;i<=1;i--)
```

This for loop will never be entered. At the beginning `i` is set to 5. Then `i<=1` is tested, which will return `false` and the for loop is skipped.

You should do this instead:

```
for(i=5;i>=1;i--)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I understand that the problem is on my logic!

Answer (score 1):

error in the loop in the stop condition.
Use

```
for(i=5;i>=1;i--)
```

instead of:

```
for(i=5;i<=1;i--)
```